# My Xubuntu boot in console mode, how to fix

Tags: 16.04, xubuntu, kde, startup

My Xubuntu 16.04 always starts in console mode, it loads GUI only when I type "startx" in terminal.

How to fix this?

Comment: what is the output of `systemctl get-default`?

Comment: I think I found the problem - my password was 3 characters, I set up 8 characters - and it seems to boot correctly

Comment: Strange, but cool ;)